# Fun with delegate casting -> InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've encountered an interesting problem, see the following code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        var testDelegate = (System.Delegate)(Action)(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey!");
        });
    }
}
```

This works as expected (does nothing, as we don't invoke anything), but now replace the "(Action)" with "new Action" and see what happens:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testDelegate = (System.Delegate)new Action(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey!");
        });
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when I try to run it I get an "InvalidProgramException". Any thoughts on why this happens?

**EDIT**

This is the DEBUG build, the release build didn't show the same problem.

IL for Main:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       3 (0x3)
  .maxstack  0
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Delegate testDelegate)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

IL for the delegate:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  '<Main>b__0'() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hey!"
  IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::'<Main>b__0'
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, and didn't expect to. Are you sure the sample is correct? If so, can you provide more info (framework version etc.)?

Comment: The above code works just fine...

Comment: @Ani Done this in visual studio 2008 sp1, Target Framework 3.5. I've been able to reproduce this on two different machines, one Win XP and one Win7. (The vs2008 install is the same though)...

Comment: Could you include the generated IL for Main using ildasm?  I see nothing wrong with this example code offhand.

Comment: @Peter Huene: I've posted the IL.

Comment: @Mr Happy: Looks like a compiler bug; I've replied with an answer.

Comment: Adding a "/optimize+" option to the Csc.exe also solves/hides the problem. That's why a Release build doesn't show this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a C# compiler bug if that generated IL for Main is accurate.  The instruction at IL_0001 in Main pops something off the evaluation stack that isn't there.  The JIT compiler notices this and raises InvalidProgramException when Main is being JIT compiled.

Edit: My guess is that this is the compiler bug you're running into: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/371711/invalidprogramexception-c-compiler-3-5

Comment: Not to mention maxstack is 0.  I don't have VS 2008 SP1 around to see if I can reproduce this, unfortunately.

Comment: @M$: EPIC fail on the `we won't be able to get to get to this fix for the next version of Visual Studio`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: As my laptop only has Windows on a VM and the VM doesn't have VS installed in it, I can't confirm if it was addressed in 2010.  Usually an accepted connect bug would generate enough nag emails for the assigned developer to close it out properly had it been resolved.  As a former Microsoft developer, I must say that not being able to quickly address customer issues because of a long, cumbersome release cycle drove me crazy.

Comment: @Peter Huene: Ah that must be it. Thanks for finding it! I never thought I'd stumble upon a compiler bug for C# in my life :o. Anyway, here's the command line for compiling it with the 3.5 compiler: "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /out:invalidProg2.exe /target:exe Program.cs"

Comment: @Peter: Huh, interesting... yeah, I would imagine it'd drive me crazy too. That doesn't sound fun, hearing people complain about something but not being able to address it in a timely manner... especially when people aren't aware that it's not really your fault. :\

Comment: @Mr Happy: I think people that discover "silent bad codegen" bugs (bugs where the compiler backend or the JIT compiler generates bad code without any warnings/errors) deserve some sort of consolation prize :)  They can be nasty bugs to track down indeed.

Comment: Well, at least it's fixed in vs2010/ Csc.exe v4.0 (just confirmed that) :-) Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Exactly!  Worse when there's no workaround and you've already committed the fix into a "next version" branch.  Unless it's a bug with wide or devastating impact (or the customer has a service contract to produce a private hotfix), the customer won't see the fix for potentially many years due to the time it takes to release the product and the time it takes the customer to migrate to the new version.  If they're lucky, it'd meet the bar for a previous version service pack and be ported to an SP branch.

Comment: @Peter: My sympathies... that's definitely frustrating indeed, for both the developers and the customers. :( Why don't they have some sort of "unofficial release", kind of like the FAST Publish articles? That way, people can get fixes to problems more quickly, with the understanding that since they're not official releases, there won't be support for them.